# When did the Running of the Bulls begin?

Tags: spain

Earliest reference I can find is 1878 on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_of_the_Bulls). This article, [Deathwish as lifestyle: why people run with the bulls | Miguel-Anxo Murado](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2015/jul/09/run-with-the-bulls-spanish-pamplona), says it’s a “a relatively recent creation”. So do we have a historical basis for when it began?

Comment: [Spanish article](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encierro_(tauromaquia)) mentions records from as far as 1215. Do you maybe mean just in Pamplona?

Comment: Earliest instance anywhere in Spain. I guess that's the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [first recorded instance](http://www.medievalum.com/los-encierros-mas-antiguos-de-espana/) of the Running of the Bulls seems to date back to 1215, but I can't speak Spanish so if anyone wants to amend this answer, please do.